# Computing the similarity between tracks

Tags: gpx, tracking

I need a way of comparing two tracks (they will most likely be GPX files), i.e., 2 arrays of lat-longs.  I need to write some code that will compare the two arrays and give me a measure of how close they are to one another.  I am testing various methods of determining location against a known route and would like to compare them.

Would the sum of the cross-track errors be sufficient?

I have seen some articles on Hausdorff distance (and dimension) and in particular Wikipedia describes "A measure for the dissimilarity of two shapes is given by Hausdorff distance up to isometry", which looks promising but I confess I don't understand what this means let alone how to implement the algorithm in code.

In short I would like to be able to state that method 1 is twice as good as method 2 at determining location.

Comment: Connect ends, convert to polygon. Area / length is your mismatch.